# Problem with Ajax Click on Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a AJAX action link.

On Click this posts to the controller. The controller sends back ascx view that is supposed to update a div in the original page.

This works fine when running from WebDev server.

However, in IIS environment, the original page is gone and the new view ends up showing on its own.

Please help.

**Environment: IIS7, ASP.NET MVC 1.1, VS 2010**

Comment: Hi. Why don't you post the code that you're using to retrieve the view? You can use $.ajax to call the view from client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accord with Cyril Gupta's comment above, you should probably post some code as this is rather vague.

I do have one debugging hint for you in this that you can try. When running the site on IIS, view source and make sure the ajax javascript files are linked in the header. I see this behavior in new projects when I forget to reference the js files before running the page. Maybe the same thing is happening to you.

Comment: Correct, You have to do this
 <script src='<%= Url.Content( "~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" ) %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='<%= Url.Content( "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" ) %>' type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src='<%= Url.Content( "~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ) %>' type="text/javascript"></script>